# Qual a diferença de syscall e call em assembly?

Tags: assembly

O seguinte código simples que escrevi, baseado em um código que li em um livro, não estava compilando:

```
;myhello
section .data
    msg db "Boa tarde",0
    NL db 0xa
section .bss
section .text
    global main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx,9
    call
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi, NL
    mov rdx,1
    call
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi,0
    call
```

E estava imprimindo o seguinte erro:

```
myhello.asm:14: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
myhello.asm:19: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
myhello.asm:22: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

Como o problema estava em `call`, eu mudei para `syscall` e o programa passou a funcionar. No entanto, eu não sei o porquê.

Qual a diferença entre call e syscall em assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Near Relative Call**

```
call rel16/rel32
```

Esta é a call que usamos não tem segredo. Ela basicamente recebe um número negativo ou positivo indicando o número de bytes que devem ser desviados

**Near Absolute Call**

Diferente da chamada relativa que indica um número de bytes a serem somados com `RIP`, numa chamada absoluta você passa o endereço exato de onde você quer fazer a chamada.
Você pode experimentar fazer uma chamada assim:

```
mov  rax, rotulo
call rax
```

**Far Call**

```
call seg16:off16   ; Em 16-bit
call seg16:off32   ; Em 32-bit

call mem16:16  ; Em 16-bit
call mem16:32  ; Em 32-bit
call mem16:64  ; Em 64-bit
```

As chamadas far são todas absolutas e recebem no operando um valor seguindo o formato de especificar um offset seguido do segmento de 16-bit.
No nasm, um valor imediato pode ser passado da seguinte forma:

```
call 0x1234:0xabcdef99
```

Onde o valor a esquerda especifica o segmento e o da direita o offset. Detalhe que esta instrução não é suportada em 64-bit.
O segundo tipo de far call, suportado em 64-bit, é o que recebe como operando um valor  na memória. Mas perceba que temos um near call que recebe o mesmo tipo de argumento.
Por padrão o nasm irá montar as instruções como near e não far. Mas você pode evitar essa ambiguidade explicitando com keywords do nasm, que são bem intuitivas:

```
call [rbx]       ; Próximo e absoluto
call near [rbx]  ; Próximo e absoluto
call far [rbx]   ; Distante
```

O near espera o endereço do offset em memória, não tem segredo. Mas o far espera o offset seguido do segmento.

**Syscall**

Uma chamada de sistema, ou syscall (abreviação para system call), **é algo muito parecido com uma call mas com a diferença nada sutil de que é o kernel do sistema operacional quem irá executar o código.**
O kernel, caso não saiba, é a parte principal de um sistema operacional. Ele é a base de todo o restante do sistema que roda sobre controle do kernel.
*O Linux na verdade é um kernel, um sistema operacional "Linux" na verdade é um sistema operacional que usa o kernel Linux.*

Em x86-64 existe uma instrução que foi feita especificamente para fazer chamadas de sistema e o nome dela é, intuitivamente, syscall.
Ela não recebe nenhum operando e a especificação de qual código ela irá executar e com quais argumentos é definido por uma convenção de chamada assim como no caso das funções.

**Convenção de syscall x86-64**

A convenção para efetuar uma chamada de sistema em Linux x86-64 é bem simples, basta definir RAX para o número da syscall que você quer executar e outros 6 registradores são usados para passar argumentos.
Em syscalls que recebem menos do que 6 argumentos, não é necessário definir o valor dos registradores restantes porque não serão utilizados.
O retorno da syscall fica em RAX assim como na convenção de chamada da linguagem C.